# I have problems with passing values to recvfrom and sendto functions in c

Tags: c, sockets, udp

when compiler reaches  reliableRecv i get an eroor
  when compiler reaches  reliableRecv i get an eroor

```
 int rvsock;

    rvsock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
struct sockaddr_in saddr;
struct sockaddr_in caddr;

if (rvsock < 0){
    perror("Failed to create the socket!!");
    exit(1);
}   

//we mark the memory pointed by saddr with 0
memset(&saddr,0,sizeof(saddr) );

saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
saddr.sin_port = htons(port);

err = bind(rvsock, (struct sockaddr*)&saddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if(err < 0){
    perror("Failed to bind");
    exit(1);
}

unsigned int len;
len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

reliableRecv(rvsock,filename,1024,(struct sockaddr*)&caddr,(size_t *)&len);
```

and reliableRecv is defined like this

```
 int reliableRecv(int sockfd,void* buffer,size_t bufferlen,struct sockaddr      *src_addr,size_t *srclen)
{
    int n=recvfrom(sockfd,buffer,bufferlen,0,src_addr,&srclen);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Please post all your code, how you invoke the compiler, and the error.

Comment: 'I get an error'.  Well, that's perfectly clear then.

Comment: 'I get an error' is not an acceptable problem description. You're supposed to post the error message here. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. You pretend `unsigned long` is `size_t` which is not necessarily accurate:

   ```
   unsigned int len;
   len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

   reliableRecv(rvsock,filename,1024,(struct sockaddr*)&caddr,(size_t *)&len);
   ```

   You should be using:

   ```
   size_t len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
   int nbytes = reliableRecv(rvsock, filename, 1024, (struct sockaddr *)&caddr, &len);
   ```

   Generally, you should avoid casting pointers other than `void *` (or one of the various `char *` types) to other pointer types.  However, the `struct sockaddr *` cast is necessary, and 'harmless', even though from most perspectives, it is undesirable.  The sockets interface was designed before `void *` was an option.
2. You pass a `size_t **` to a function that expects a `size_t *`:

   ```
   int reliableRecv(int sockfd, void *buffer, size_t bufferlen, struct sockaddr *src_addr, size_t *srclen)
   {
       int n=recvfrom(sockfd,buffer,bufferlen,0,src_addr,&srclen);
       return n;
   }
   ```

   You should be using:

   ```
   int reliableRecv(int sockfd, void *buffer, size_t bufferlen,
                    struct sockaddr *src_addr, size_t *srclen)
   {
       int n = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, bufferlen, 0, src_addr, srclen);
       return n;
   }
   ```